# Changing background-image of unselected elements when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm doing a software interface prototype in HTML format and on the menu I have a bunch of buttons that are list itens with background-images. when I click on then the background-image changes to show that the button is selected, I did that by .replace() the name of the url folder:

```
#menu ul.icons li {
background-image:url(images/edit-menu/icons/hand.png);
background-size:contain;
display:block;
```

}

```
ul class="icons"> 
    <li class="um"></li>
    <li class="dois">
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li></li>            
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="tres"></li>
    <li class="quatro"></li>
    <li class="cinco"></li>
    <li class="seis"></li>
    <li class="sete"></li>
    <li class="oito"></li>
    <li class="nove"></li>
    <li class="dez"></li>
</ul>

$("#menu ul.icons li").click(function() {
var urlIcon = $(this).css('background-image').replace('icons', 'selected');
$(this).css('background-image', urlIcon);
});
```

But now I need that when a button is clicked any other button that was in a 'selected' state changes back to unselected, so I need to change the folder of the url of the background-image from 'selected' back to 'icons'. I tried using replace() and siblings() but it didn't work.

Comment: It would help if you could post the code that didn't work.

Comment: What I would do is have 2 classes - for background not selected and background selected. The on click you can look through all elements in that area of the DOM and remove class "selected" from everywhere and then only add class selected to a currently clicked one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define the icons in your css, and manipulate them by toggling an active class in your javascript.

CSS:

```
#menu ul.icons li {
  background-image:url(images/edit-menu/icons/hand.png);
} 

#menu ul.icons li.active {
  background-image:url(images/edit-menu/icons/active.png);
}
```

Jquery:

```
$("#menu ul.icons li").click(function(){
  $(this).siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

If you needed icons specific to each list item, you can update the css to be specific where needed, but the Jquery can stay the same.

Comment: I need the icons to be specific, so I add a class to each list item(um, dois, tres, quatro, etc), so if I use your code I get something like class="um .active", so them removeClass("active") won't work cause there's no class with just that name.

Comment: It should be class="um active" (no dot) and removeClass("active") will work because it will remove that class, leaving you with class="um". Try it.

Comment: It seems like I can get #menu ul.icons li.um active to work even if I declare it on the HTML, I think it's because of the space in the name of the class.

Comment: Edit: Ok I made this to work by in the css declaring as this :  #menu ul.icons li.um.active, with a dot instead of a space. Now the only thing that doesn't work is the .siblings().removeClass() part

Comment: Edit: made it work with $(this).siblings().removeClass("active"); , thanks @thebiffboff